# Simple Regex issue on beginning the sentence

Tags: regex

There are simple 3 sentences, and I want to take the middle one. I try to use this regex but it takes first and second sentence together. I want to take only the second sentence.

**My regex : (RIWS.*)**

Sentences :

1. `>>> RIWS   "SFGHMIS C.A-VIT_SOURCE;2.7.2.1"`
2. `RIWS   "XXX:YYY HMIS D.B-VIT_SOURCE;3.4.3.1"`
3. `Operation completed`

The problem is selecting the beginning of the sentence. My regex takes both first and second sentence but i only should take the second sentence. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use line start anchor:

```
^RIWS.*$
```